# Drawing a family of geodesics in a 3-dimensional space

Tags: plotting

I want to plot a family of geodesics given by parametric equations $x(t), y(t), z(t)$. Unfortunately the following code (that works for plots of scalar functions) does not work:

```
fx[t_, w_, c_, \[Alpha]_] = (2 c Sin[(t * w)/2] Cos[\[Alpha] + (t *w)/2])/w; 
fy[t_, w_, c_, \[Alpha]_] = ((2 c) Sin[(t w)/2] Sin[\[Alpha] + (t w)/2])/w;
fz[t_, w_, c_, \[Alpha]_] = t w ((c^2 (((1 - Cos[t w ]) Sin[2 \[Alpha] + t w])/(t w) + (1 - Sin[t w]/(t w))))/(2 w^2) + 1);
wmin = 0.01; wmax = 2; dw = 0.5;
cmin = 0.01; cmax = 2; dc = 0.5;
\[Alpha]min = 0.01; \[Alpha]max = 2; d\[Alpha] = 0.5;
ParametricPlot3D[Evaluate@Table[{fx[t, w, c, \[Alpha]], fy[t, w, c, \[Alpha]], fz[t, w, c, \[Alpha]]}, {w, wmin, wmax, dw}, {c, cmin, cmax, dc}, {\[Alpha], \[Alpha]min, \[Alpha]max, d\[Alpha]}], {t, 0, 1}]
```

Have you got any idea how to fix it?

Comment: Try `ParametricPlot3D[Evaluate @ Flatten[Table[(* stuff *)], 2], {t, 0, 1}]`. Remember that `ParametricPlot3D[]` needs a list of triples, and not a nested list of them.

Comment: Thank you, I will check if it works. I have previously used Flatten without any arguments, But maybe Flatten[, 2] will work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

J. M. needs help. suggested in comments the following solution

```
ParametricPlot3D[Evaluate@Flatten[Table[{fx[t, w, c, \[Alpha]], fy[t, w, c, \[Alpha]], fz[t, w, c, \[Alpha]]}, {w, wmin, wmax, dw}, {c, cmin, cmax, dc}, {\[Alpha], \[Alpha]min, \[Alpha]max, d\[Alpha]}], 2], {t, 0,1}]
```

It worked.